# Defining a JOIN-cursor and a matching row type (with least code)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, row

I am currently working with a PL/SQL batch process in Oracle in which I need to process data extracted from a file.

I have currently managed to store these information in a few temporary tables, but they also link to permanent tables.

For my PL/SQL procedure, I have defined a cursor like the following:

```
CURSOR myCursor is
SELECT A.field1, A.field2..... C.fieldN
FROM A JOIN .... JOIN C;
```

To this cursor, I'll apply the `FOR ALL` operator. My algorithm requires me to perform some validation on the data. Different validation functions require different subset of data in input, which I can find in the record type returned by the cursor.

For coding simplicity, I would like ALL the validation functions to accept and return (the second one is actually possible per system specifications) respectively the same type of argument.

Ie.

```
FUNCTION CheckA(param1 IN IN_RECORD_TYPE) RETURN VALIDATION_OUTCOME;
FUNCTION CheckB(param1 IN IN_RECORD_TYPE) RETURN VALIDATION_OUTCOME;
FUNCTION CheckC(param1 IN IN_RECORD_TYPE) RETURN VALIDATION_OUTCOME;
FUNCTION CheckC(param1 IN IN_RECORD_TYPE) RETURN VALIDATION_OUTCOME;
```

The reason behind this is that I can store the function name in a workflow table and obtain the specific function to call as a plain join :) :)

#### My straight question is

How do I declare `IN_RECORD_TYPE` in order to match the row type returned by the above cursor with least code?

I know I can define a custom record type matching the cursor outcome, then build the input object field by field. But that doesn't seem a good practice. `CURSOR`s don't define the `%TYPE` property.

What can I do for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass in a record using the cursor's `ROWTYPE`.  You shouldn't need to declare a separate record type.  Something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package test_pkg
  2  as
  3    cursor c1
  4        is select e.ename,
  5                  d.dname
  6             from emp e,
  7                  dept d
  8            where e.deptno = d.deptno;
  9    procedure p1( p_arg IN c1%rowtype );
 10    procedure p2( p_arg IN c1%rowtype );
 11* end;
 12  /

Package created.
```